# Problems uploading MySQL database using phpMyAdmin on local machine

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am able to connect to my MySQL databases on my servers remotely with no problems and can query and truncate the tables fine. I **cannot** however, upload (via import) the database files.

```
upload_max_filesize = 40M
post_max_size = 40M
```

I have also uploaded the php.ini file to my server.

Answer (score 1):

If you can connect remotely with no problems, then don't use phpmyadmin to do your restore. Use another remote tool that doesn't use php.

try go to `my.cnf in /etc/mysqlan`d where it says

```
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

Change it to your server's IP address. Restart mySQL. That way you should be able to connect remotely using something like mySQL Workbench (on their website), and upload the .sql

I recommend changing it back afterwards to avoid other problems.

Also make sure you make a user who has access from anywhere (%) or at least your home IP (wherever you're trying to connect from), and with enough privileges to restore the database. (Although if you make a root user with access from %, you can sometimes not get in using phpMyAdmin anymore.)

Load the file to your server with FTP/SSH and use SSH to restore the database with mysql commands.